# Can I first open an account on an exchange then later on transfer to my wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallet, exchanges, mtgox

I'd like, at one point, to create myself a bitcoin wallet using an offline computer and then store that wallet in a safe (either printed, encrypted, on a sheet of paper or encrypted on a USB stick). However that requires quite some time and some skills, which I don't have yet (related to bitcoin -- when it comes to Linux / boot-only CDs/DVDs and PKCS etc. there's no problem: I'm a long time Linux user and I do know a bit about crypto stuff).

Meanwhile I may want to already buy bitcoins online (say if a crash happens I may decide to buy some).

If I open an account on, say, mtgox, can I immediately buy bitcoins and if I can, can I then transfer the very bitcoins I just bought to my own personal wallet (the one that I'll generate later on offline and put its private part in a safe).

As a side-question: where are the bitcoins that I buy on mtgox stored? In a wallet belonging to mtgox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I open an account on, say, mtgox, can I immediately buy bitcoins and if I can, can I then transfer the very bitcoins I just bought to my own personal wallet (the one that I'll generate later on offline and put its private part in a safe).

Yes, that's a basic Bitcoin withdrawal.

> As a side-question: where are the bitcoins that I buy on mtgox stored? In a wallet belonging to mtgox?

Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to verify your identity and address with Mt. Gox and Bitstamp before you are able to withdraw coins or USD. BTC-E does not have that requirement for small amounts but it is a lot harder to get money into. So overall there is no "quick" way to get into bitcoin. You have to put in the time to get verified and also to learn what bitcoin is and how it works. It is unlike any other currency so if you don't know how it works you are liable to loose a lot of money. For example exchange accounts get hacked all the time so you never leave a large amount there and using an online wallet like blockchain.info is also asking for trouble.